# Processing video library does not work on Linux (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: java, linux, video, webcam, processing

I have a problem.

I'm trying to run the `Mirror` sample from the Processing `video` library, with the latest version of Processing (2.0.3).  However, I get this error;

```
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 14: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
libEGL warning: failed to create a pipe screen for i965
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gstreamer-0.10': libgstreamer-0.10.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at com.jogamp.common.util.awt.AWTEDTExecutor.invoke(AWTEDTExecutor.java:58)
        at jogamp.opengl.awt.AWTThreadingPlugin.invokeOnOpenGLThread(AWTThreadingPlugin.java:100)
        at jogamp.opengl.ThreadingImpl.invokeOnOpenGLThread(ThreadingImpl.java:205)
        at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading.java:172)
        at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:191)
        at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:483)
        at processing.opengl.PGL.requestDraw(PGL.java:1149)
        at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.requestDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1604)
        at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2176)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gstreamer-0.10': libgstreamer-0.10.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:163)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:236)
        at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:379)
        at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GNative.loadNativeLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GNative.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GstNative.load(GstNative.java:42)
        at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GstNative.load(GstNative.java:39)
        at org.gstreamer.Gst.<clinit>(Gst.java:59)
        at processing.video.Video.initImpl(Unknown Source)
        at processing.video.Video.init(Unknown Source)
        at processing.video.Capture.initGStreamer(Unknown Source)
        at processing.video.Capture.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at testvideo.setup(testvideo.java:46)
        at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2280)
        at processing.opengl.PGL$PGLListener.display(PGL.java:2601)
        at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:588)
        at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:572)
        at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$7.run(GLCanvas.java:1054)
        at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1034)
        at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:909)
        at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$8.run(GLCanvas.java:1065)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:199)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:666)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:627)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:625)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:636)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

This means I can't use video, of course.  **Any tips on fixing this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `libgstreamer-0.10.so` library, or it is not in the LD path.  The most likely problem is that you have not installed the necessary packages from your distribution.

Comment: How can I tell if it's in the LD or not?

Comment: If you are getting this error then it's not in the LD path, probably because it doesn't exist on your system.

Comment: Synaptic tells me otherwise.  EDIT: Ah, now I'm getting an error with another library `gstinterfaces`.  Lemme try that one.

Comment: Ah ha, it worked!  However, I don't know exactly which package it was that did the trick.  Would you happen to know, for people reading this answer in the future?

Comment: @JesseTG It would be specific to your particular distribution.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @JesseTG's comment:

For me, the necessary packages seemed to be the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
```

The first package fixed the first link error, the second fixed the subsequent gstinterfaces link error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Andrew, yes it does answer the question.